# Deploying a plug-in for Autodesk motionbuilder 2011

Tags: plugins

I have to make an installer for motionbuilder 2011 for 32 bit and 64 bit.
The installer should detect and deploy the corresponding plug-ins.
One of the 64 bit machines has both versions installed on it but the registry shows only one of them at a time.
Is there any way to detect both the installed versions and deploy the corresponding plug-ins in their install directories?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you have to query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE64 to get MoBu 64-bit path. For example, using Inno Setup script:

32-bit path

```
RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, Software\Autodesk\MotionBuilder\2011, 'InstallPath', path)
```

64-bit path

```
RegQueryStringValue(HKLM64, Software\Autodesk\MotionBuilder\2011, 'InstallPath', path)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Neil for the info. But it is slightly too late for it be implemented. But it is always great to have knowledge. Cheers.